# Visual Studio 2012 DTE change focus to a new solution item

Tags: c#, automation, visual-studio-2012, envdte

I am trying to automate changing focus from one .ProjectItem in the solution explorer to another .ProjectItem. I want to change focus from one item to another item programatically and cannot seem to figure out how.
Here is what I have so far:

```
dteInstance.Solution.Projects(2).ProjectItems(3).Focus
```

I realize there is no .Focus property on a ProjectItem but this is what I need to do. So in code, I am on the ProjectItem in the solution that I want to set focus to but cannot click it or find a way to set focus on it. I can read the items properties like .Name etc. How can I set focus to the .ProjectItem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Query all UIHierarchyItems of solution recursively,and find the exact UIHierarchyItem that equivalent to your ProjectItem.Then call UIHierarchyItem.Select()

```
UIHierarchyItem uiItem = SolutionHelper.FindHierarchyItem(dteInstance.Solution.Projects(2).ProjectItems(3));
uiItem?.Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect);
```

```
        private static readonly EnvDTE80.DTE2 _applicationObject = 
(EnvDTE80.DTE2)ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE));
        
        public static UIHierarchy SolutionExplorerNode
        {
            get
            {
                return _applicationObject.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer;
            }
        }

        public static UIHierarchyItem FindHierarchyItem(object item)
        {
            ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
            UIHierarchyItems items = SolutionExplorerNode.UIHierarchyItems.Item(1).UIHierarchyItems;
            Stack s = new Stack();
            CreateItemsStack(s, item);

            UIHierarchyItem last = null;
            while (s.Count != 0)
            {
                object o = s.Pop();

                last = null;
                foreach (UIHierarchyItem child in items)
                {
                    if (child.Object == o)
                    {
                        last = child;
                        items = child.UIHierarchyItems;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return last;
        }

        private static void CreateItemsStack(Stack s, object item)
        {
            ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
            if (item is ProjectItem)
            {
                ProjectItem pi = (ProjectItem)item;
                s.Push(pi);
                CreateItemsStack(s, pi.Collection.Parent);
            }
            else if (item is Project)
            {
                Project p = (Project)item;
                s.Push(p);
                if (p.ParentProjectItem != null)
                {
                    CreateItemsStack(s, p.ParentProjectItem);
                }
            }
        }
```